# Silverstripe 3.5.1 - Check if internal link is a redirector page, and if so, check redirector page's link type

Tags: silverstripe

I'm working on updating a rotating banner feature for a site that allows for internal links to be associated with each banner image. Some banners need to link to external website pages, though, and for those, I'm referencing a redirector page in the sitetree and setting the redirect to be "another website."

However, the external link does not open in a new tab. I am trying to figure out a way to check if the internal link value is a redirector page type, and if so, if that redirector page is set to an external link. If so, then add "target=_blank."

I've tried this but no luck--the link always opens in the same window regardless of what type of link I have set for the redirector page:

```
   <div class="Top-Banner clearfix" <% if $BackgroundImage %>style="background: url('$BackgroundImage.URL');"<% end_if %>>
        <% if $InternalURL %>
            <a href="$InternalURL.Link"
            <% if $ClassName = 'RedirectorPage' %>
                <% if $RedirectionType = 'External' %>
               target="_blank"<% end_if %>
            <% end_if %>>
        <% end_if %>
        <div id="Home-Banner-{$Pos}" class="Top-Banner-Inner clearfix" style="background: url('$Image.URL');background-size:cover !important;background-position:center center !important;">
            <div class="Top-Banner-Content clearfix">
                <h1 class="Top-Banner-Headline">$Header</h1>
                <div class="Top-Banner-Sub-Text">
                    $Body
                </div>
                <div class="Top-Banner-Buttons clearfix">
                    <input type="button" value="Patient Portal - Login" onmouseover="this.style.background='#$PatientPortalBtnHoverColor'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#$PatientPortalBtnColor'" style="background-color: #$PatientPortalBtnColor;" onclick="window.location.href='$PatientPortalInternalURL.Link'" />
                    <input type="button" value="Learn More" onmouseover="this.style.background='#$LearnMoreBtnHoverColor'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#$LearnMoreBtnColor'" style="background-color: #$LearnMoreBtnColor;" onclick="window.location.href='$LearnMoreInternalURL.Link'" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% if $InternalURL %>
            </a>
        <% end_if %>
    </div>
```

Also tried:

```
<% if $InternalURL %>
    <a href="$InternalURL.Link"
       <% if $RedirectionType='External' %>
       target="_blank"<% end_if %>>
<% end_if %>
```

Also tried this:

```
  <% if $InternalURL %>
    <a href="$InternalURL.Link"
        <% if $InternalURL.ClassName = 'RedirectorPage' %>
           target="_blank"
        <% end_if %>>
    <% end_if %>
```

which works as it does recognize the page type as a RedirectorPage, and I can set target="_blank" and whatever else, but using it in conjunction with $RedirectionType = 'External" does not work:

```
 <% if $InternalURL %>
    <a href="$InternalURL.Link"
        <% if $InternalURL.ClassName = 'RedirectorPage' %>
            <% if $RedirectionType = 'Internal' %>target="_blank"<% end_if %>
        <% end_if %>>
 <% end_if %>
```

I need to be able to check, though if the redirector page is set to an external link--I can't just have the link open in a new window simply because the link is from a redirector page. The content manager may want to use an internal link and stay on the same page when the link is clicked.

Here is the code for the RotatorImage data object:

```
<?php

class RotatorImage extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'SortOrder' => 'Int',
        'Header' => 'varchar',
        'Body' => 'HTMLText',
    );

    // One-to-one relationship with gallery page
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image',
        'BackgroundImage' => 'Image',
        'Page' => 'Page',
        'InternalURL' => 'SiteTree',
    );

    // tidy up the CMS by not showing these fields
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","PageID");
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","SortOrder");
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TreeDropdownField("InternalURLID","Banner Link","SiteTree"));

        return $fields;
    }

    // Tell the datagrid what fields to show in the table
    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'ID' => 'ID',
        'Title' => 'Title',
        'Thumbnail' => 'Thumbnail',
        'InternalURLID' => 'Internal URL',
    );

    // this function creates the thumnail for the summary fields to use
    public function getThumbnail() {
        return $this->Image()->CMSThumbnail();
    }

    public function canEdit($member=null) {
        return true;
    }

    public function canDelete($member=null) {
        return true;
    }

    public function canCreate($member=null){
        return true;
    }

    public function canPublish($member=null){
        return true;
    }

    public function canView($member=null){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `InternalURL`? Is it a has_one relationship to a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution after playing around a bit:

```
 <% if $InternalURL %>
     <a href="$InternalURL.Link"
          <% if **$InternalURL.RedirectionType == 'External'** %>
               target="_blank"<% end_if %>>
  <% end_if %>
```

I figured out you can check redirection type of the selected page using the method above. Never would have guessed it was possible until I experimented for a while.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear whether you're looping over Page objects or Banner objects but if it is Pages then the following would work:

```
    <% loop $Pages %>
        <% if $ClassName = 'RedirectorPage' %>
            <% if $RedirectionType == "External" %>
                <a href="$Link" target="_blank">$Title (External Redirect)</a>
            <% else %>
                <a href="$Link">$Title (Internal Redirect)</a>
            <% end_if %>
        <% else %> 
            <a href="$Link>$Title (Page Link)</a>
        <% end_if %>
    <% end_loop %>
```

If it is a Banner object or something similar you need to make sure you're checking the RedirectionType on the Page object, not the Banner itself:

```
    <% loop $Banners %>
        <% if $Page.ClassName = 'RedirectorPage' %>
            <% if $Page.RedirectionType == "External" %>
                <a href="$Page.Link" target="_blank">$Page.Title (External Redirect)</a>
            <% else %>
                <a href="$Page.Link">$Page.Title (Internal Redirect)</a>
            <% end_if %>
        <% else %> 
            <a href="$Page.Link>$Page.Title (Page Link)</a>
        <% end_if %>
    <% end_loop %>
```

If this doesn't make sure please post your data object and I can have another look.

Comment: I posted the code for my RotatorImage data object for reference